# Hidden Markov Model - HMM with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, hidden-markov-models

i need to know how to use **HMM on top of Apache Spark**. Its not present in MLlib. 
**Is there any alternatives ?**

Thanks

Elsayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can find is a [2 year old implementation](https://github.com/skrusche63/spark-intent/tree/master/src/main/scala/de/kp/scala/hmm) on spark.

You might want to investigate using something other than spark or HMM or just bite the bullet and implement it yourself. Implementing the viterbi algorithm is not particularly hard, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730066/1269969) is my many years old implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`HMM` algorithm - excerpts from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model

> `Hidden Markov Model (HMM)` is a statistical Markov model in which the system being modeled is assumed to be a `Markov process` with unobserved (i.e. hidden) states. The hidden markov model can be represented as the simplest `dynamic Bayesian network`.
>
> A hidden Markov model can be considered a generalization of a `mixture model` where the `hidden variables` (or `latent variables`), which control the mixture component to be selected for each observation, are related through a Markov process rather than independent of each other.
>
> Applying the principle of `dynamic programming`, this problem, too, can be handled efficiently using the `forward algorithm`.

Have not seen algorithms around the above concepts implemented on `Spark`.

`Spark` can support "beyond map-reduce" algorithms but the only thing with `dynamic programming` I could find was https://github.com/bbengfort/brisera

> A Python implementation of a distributed seed and reduce algorithm (similar to BlastReduce and CloudBurst) that utilizes RDDs (resilient distributed datasets) to perform fast iterative analyses and `dynamic programming` without relying on *"chained `MapReduce` jobs"*.

`Mahout` has an `HMM` implementation but unsure if it is distributed
https://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/hidden-markov-models.html